# Android control TabHost Layout through code

Tags: android

I set the TabHost through the code without using the Layout XML.  How do I control Tab appearing at the bottom instead on top. normally its controlled through XML by  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
 TabHost host=getTabHost();


    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Offers")
            .setIndicator("Offers", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_light))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Account")
            .setIndicator("Account", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_wrench))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));

    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Settings")
            .setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_user))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));

    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Awards")
            .setIndicator("Awards", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_list))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, List_Items.class)));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using relative layout (since you are using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`).
Then I belive you need to create RelativeLayout layout parameters and apply them to your TabWidget, something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(..., ...);
rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
tw.setLayoutParams(rllp); //where tw is your TabWidget
```

It's programmatical equivalent of using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: I don't see any function of  addRule for the params.  And I don't see any Layout.ALign_PARENT_BOTTOM=1 too.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: OK, I implemented it. syntax is OK but the system crashed when in emulator. The lines I added are    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    
     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);  
          
     host.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: instead of `host` apply it to TabWidget: `tw = getTabWidget(); tw.setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: btw, TabHost should be in your xml layout with attribute `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"`, otherwise `getTabHost()` won't work; the same goes to `getTabWidget()`

Comment: I don't use XML and I only use host.addTab function to get tabwidget.    Right now it's showing up on emulator with tabs on top instead of bottom.  I mean if I use XML then I don't need this hassle I just set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in my XML.

Comment: did you try applying `params` to tabWidget?